# How to change the colour of slides wordart using Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Can you suggest a way to change the color of WordArt in Google slides using Apps script?

When I refer to the object as a shape I get an error message about the object not being of type shape. But I can't see any methods for the WordArt object type that will allow me to change its colour.

I've only limited experience with Apps script but surely there must be a way!

```
SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById('g2b10b3710e9_4_1').asShape().getFill().setSolidFill(250, 250, 250, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For educational purposes, this is a sample script to access the WordArt Object in Google Slides Apps Script.

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation(); 
  var slide = presentation.getSlideById('slideID');
  var wordArt = slide.getWordArts()[0];

}
```

But as of the moment, all features of Google Apps Script in modifying WordArts in Google Slides is limited to scaling, positioning, copying etc. There are no features as of the moment to edit fill colors, or even rendered text of a Word Art. But I suggest you submit a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191598&template=823918) instead.

**SUGGESTION:**

One way of achieving any changes you want to a Word Art is creating a hidden slide instead with templated WordArts, and simply accessing those WordArt objects and duplicating it to a slide of your choice. But this is only a suggestion, this still depends on the use case you intended to do.

**Reference:** https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/word-art

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I suspected. The project I'm working on is a quiz where users entering a correct answer are able to set the colour for particular parts of a diagram and the corresponding Wordart labels. WordArt characters have a border and that allows the text to show even with a white fill colour. I'll experiment importing shapes with the 'shape' of the outlined characters and if that fails to workout I'll make do with text within shapes.

Comment: I've done some experimenting and importing the wordart as a shape works well. I can colour the lettering and its borders just as I had hoped to do with the slides wordart.